# How to handle com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 4 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions in 3rd party application from our code

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I wanted to Unmarshall 3rd party java class [Inside the xsd].When unmarshelling I am getting 
**Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.**

> com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 4 counts of
>   IllegalAnnotationExceptions

When I see the xsd schema I am able to see two objects inside a class has same XMLType.
Since this is 3rd party resource I don't have privilege to work on their code.Any workaround I can make to make this work from my end.
I am using **Jdk 1.8** & **javax.xml.bind** for unmarshelling.
I googled but got to know we need to modify the base class[3rd party] which I can't do .
Any ideas would be appreciated.